# JVM Attach API Virtual Machine. What does it mean to "Attach"?

Tags: java, jvm, monitoring

I don't quite understand what it means to "attach" to another virtual machine via the [attach api](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/the_attach_api). I've read that every java program runs in its own virtual machine (see [here](http://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/jvmP.html)). So what exactly happens in memory for one program to "attach" to another jvm process so that it can get access to the other virtual machines data such as the MBeanServer? Is the bytecode of one virtual machine actually invoking a special request to the other virtual machine to get permission to access memory, or is the first virtual machine unloaded from memory, and then both sets of code share one virtual machine? I'd greatly appreciate if someone could clarify the details of what this attachment looks like from the memory viewpoint / virtual machine negotiation steps (if thats what it is called). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perfect example to explain a scenario where one jvm is attached to another is use of Java Profilers. Profilers basically are used to get the insight of another jvm for performance profiling. Application under examination is attached to profiler jvm, which introspects the heap/stack to determine different information about the examined jvm.

The standard profiler, [jvisualvm](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html), uses the [JVM TI API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jvmti/) extensively, for example to perform and monitor garbage collection. Java Management Extensions (JMX) is used as the common communications layer.

Comment: My question is concerned with what it means to "attach". Is a tcp socket opened, does serialization happen, does the vm that is being attached to have to "approve" the vm that is trying to attach to it? What is going on under the hood in order for one VM to attach to another?

Comment: This is up to the Attach API implementation (which in turn mean that you should use the same Java binary to run both programs to minimize differences).

Answer (score 0):

I debugged this and I think, It uses unix socket to communiate with the JVM process. As you can see, the attach process is trying to open the socket_file , which is under the process directory, if the file does not exist, it will try to create the attach file which should be another unix socket file to communicate with the VM.

[image: debug]